# STL vector iterator giving core dump

Tags: c++, stl

```
#include<iostream.h>
   #include<vector.h>
   int main()
   {
           vector<int> v;
           vector<int>::iterator itr=v.begin();
           v.insert(itr,10,100);
           v.insert(itr,10,100);
   }
```

this program is generating core dump after including the second insert,not able to understand why as the itr will be incremented at the time of the first insert.

Comment: No, `itr` will not be incremented by the `insert` call.

Answer (score 3):

Insert has return type in your favor. To fix your problem, you just need to reasign `itr` with returned value:

```
vector<int> v;
vector<int>::iterator itr=v.begin();
itr = v.insert(itr,10,100); //new begin
itr = v.insert(itr,10,100); //new begin
```

Another solution is to reserve space for vector:

```
vector<int> v;
v.reserve(1000);
vector<int>::iterator itr=v.begin();
v.insert(itr,10,100); //itr not invalidated
v.insert(itr,10,100);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the vector starts as empty, the first  `v.insert(itr,10,100);` increases its size, thus invalidating any iterators, so the second insertion fails because the iterator is no longer valid.

Comment: thanks for the help,worked after the code:-
worked after adding the below statement between the first and the second insert.
 itr=v.begin()+10;
which means that everytime i want to use the iterator pointer,i will have to refer to the begininnign and then use it??